# How to check if the last element inside another element is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Is there any jQuery code for finding the last `<a>` tag inside a `<div>` is focussed using keyboard. I.E. if the last `<a>` tag inside a `<div>` is focussed, a Javascript function has to be triggered

```
<div>
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
  <!-- -->
  <!-- -->
  <a>n</a>
<div>
```

Comment: You can keep the last clicked anchor tag in any variable and use that

Comment: `:last`? https://jsfiddle.net/s9mLgjce/

Answer (score 2):

just select the last `a` element and add `focus` eventlistener with JQuery

```js
$("div a:last-child").focus(function(e){
  console.log("last <a> focused");
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent infinite loop
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#">a tag</a>
  <a href="#">a tag</a>
  <a href="#">a tag</a>
  <a href="#">a tag</a>
  <a href="#">a tag</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check - https://jsfiddle.net/s9mLgjce/5/. If a tag is inside div each time it is showing.I want the last a tag inside test1 div

Comment: @Warrior In your case, use `:last` not `:last-child`. But alexis was answering regarding your posted code in question where `:last-child` is perfectly valid...

Comment: @Warrior yes sorry. A. Wolff is right, last-child depend of your html structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:last-child` selector to find the last element into `<div>` (in this case the last anchor `<a>`) and use also `.focus(<callback>)` to listen on focus event over any element:

```
$('div a:last-child').focus(function(){
    //Do whatever
});
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.